# React native error,canOverrideExistingModule=true

Tags: android, react-native

Hi I try 3 libaries(react native -(sound,sound player,play sound) to play sound but I can not play a sound onPress Togglebutton

It gives this error

[image: The error]

App.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  FlatList,
  SafeAreaView,
  TouchableOpacity,
  ImageBackground
} from 'react-native';

import { PlaySound, StopSound, PlaySoundRepeat, PlaySoundMusicVolume } from 'react-native-play-sound';
//FFE990       FFD488     FFE493    E7CE85   E7C287
const ToggleButton = (props) => {
  const [isPressed, setIsPressed] = useState(false);
  const { sample, id, onPress, item1, item2 } = props;
  const text = isPressed ? item2.sample2 : item1.sample;

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => {
        setIsPressed(!isPressed);
        onPress && onPress();
        PlaySound('./john.mp3');
      }}
      style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          width: '100%',
          height: 129,
          backgroundColor:'#E7C287',
          borderWidth: 1,
          marginTop:36,
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
          padding:8
        }}>
        <Text style={{   fontSize: 14 }}>{text}</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
  
};

const ToggleExample = () => {
  const data = [
    {sample:"Mouse",id:"0"},
    {sample:"Mouse2",id:"1"},
    ,
   ,
 ];
  const data2 = [
    {sample2:"Disney",id:"0"},
{sample2:"Sindirella",id:"1"},
];
    
  

  return (
    <ImageBackground source={require('./assets/papi2.jpg')}  style={{
      flex: 1,
      width:'100%',
      height:'100%'
    }}> 
      <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 ,alignItems: 'center',}}>
      <Text style={{marginTop:21,
    padding:16,
    marginBottom:27,
    fontSize:28,
    alignItems: 'center',
    }}>Post</Text>

      <FlatList
        data={data}
        renderItem={(entry) => {
          const { item } = entry;
          return (
            <ToggleButton
              item1={item}
              item2={data2.filter((_item) => _item.id === item.id)[0]}
            />
          );
        }}
        contentContainerStyle={{ padding: 20 }}
        ItemSeparatorComponent={() => {
          return <View style={{ flex: 1, height: 10 }} />;
        }}
        keyExtractor={(entry, index) => index.toString()}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
    </ImageBackground>
  );
  
};

export default ToggleExample;
```

That's my code on press I try to play "john.mp3" but now it says

"canOverrideExistingModule=true" in the Main activity. I searched, tried to override this func but it still says same

"Native module SoundManager tried to override,Check getPackages() ..."

MainApp.java

```
package com.post42;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import com.facebook.react.PackageList;
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.soundapp.SoundModulePackage;
import com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost =
      new ReactNativeHost(this) {
        @Override
        public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
          return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
        }
  
        @Override
        protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
          @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
          List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
          // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
          // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
          return packages;
        }

        @Override
        protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
          return "index";
        }
      };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
    initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
  }

  /**
   * Loads Flipper in React Native templates. Call this in the onCreate method with something like
   * initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
   *
   * @param context
   * @param reactInstanceManager
   */
  private static void initializeFlipper(
      Context context, ReactInstanceManager reactInstanceManager) {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
      try {
        /*
         We use reflection here to pick up the class that initializes Flipper,
        since Flipper library is not available in release mode
        */
        Class<?> aClass = Class.forName("com.post42.ReactNativeFlipper");
        aClass
            .getMethod("initializeFlipper", Context.class, ReactInstanceManager.class)
            .invoke(null, context, reactInstanceManager);
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I fix it.
Thank you

I still can't fix it

Comment: Anybody please ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you rebuild the android app after `canOverrideExistingModule=true` ?

If not please clear you cache once `cd android` and `./gradlew clean`.
And run `react-native run android`

And the above error is there because the packages now follow auto linking and you might have manually linked it

Comment: I linked it but how can I manually link in MainApplication.java